# Linking dropdownlist to database and not displaying certain records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My table in the database currently has 3 columns (id, name and role).
I am trying to create a dropdownlist based on this table, displaying the names in the dropdown only if they are of a certain role.

Below is my model and then my cshtml, when run, it displays a dropdownlist of all the entries, how do I limit these to only entries with the role "admin".

### Model

```
public class Roles
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string role { get; set; }

}
```

### cshtml:

```
            <div style="float:right;">
                @{
                    NomineesDbContext db = new NomineesDbContext();
                    var rolesList = db.roles.ToList();
                    ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(rolesList, "id", "name");
                }
                @Html.DropDownList("id", ViewBag.roles as SelectList, "PLT Member to call", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
```

### dbcontext:

```
public DbSet<Roles> roles { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that you want to select only those records from db where role = admin.
following is the code

```
NomineesDbContext db = new NomineesDbContext();
                    var rolesList = db.roles.Where(x=> x.role == "admin").ToList();
                    ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(rolesList, "id", "name");
```

However it is recommended that you should add above 3 lines of code in Associated Controller Action, adding code in View page is not a good practice